# When/how is it okay to redefine/declare variables? [functional]

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I've been learning functional programming in javascript of late, and there's one thing that's been confusing me. I can't quite understand if it's ever okay to redefine variables.

Something like: `a = a + 1` immediately throws up red flags. `a` is mutating, so that's a no go. And certainly declaring a variable like so: `var a = 10` is fine, after all we're just giving the state `10` a name. But what about something like this:

```
function f(x){
  var y = x;
  return y + x;
}
/*overlooking the fact that this code
has no meaningful purpose and could be
simplified as return 2 *x;*/
```

Is that allowed? Declaring variable y is fine, but what if we call f(x) twice? How about writing this statement with recursion? Is redeclaring variable y multiple times okay? Or is `y` just a variable that exists solely during the time that it's nested function is running.

While I was looking for the answer to this question, I came across a page about pure and impure functions. I take it that purity isn't functional programming exclusive. Further digging told me that declaring variables within a function could potentially lead to impurity. So even if I could declare variables within the scope of a function, would that be problematic? What rules do I need to adhere by to avoid compromising the purity of my functions?

Comment: When programming functionally, you are always allowed to create new state, whether as simple as a local variable or as complex as whole data structures (or both).  You just shouldn't modify already existing state.

Comment: Further, an invocation of `f` is also the creation of new state (a new activation with new parameters), whether multiple `f`'s are sequentially invoked, or there is recursion involved, each invocation of `f` is the conjuring of new state.  So, parameters within `f`, as well as local variables within `f` are new to each invocation.  Thus, invoking a functions is the creation of new state, which is allowed when programming functionally.  The creation of new state is *required* to get things done functionally, since you cannot modify existing state!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is fine, because it is a new y in each invocation of the function. A simple rule is "appears on the left of = exactly once, at the point of declaration".

Function "purity" is generally in reference to a lack of side effects, that is affecting anything outside of the function (e.g. incrementing a global counter, writing to a file, etc).

```
function impure(x) {
    x.y = 10; // Modifying x here
    return x.y * 5;
}

function pure(x) {
    var y = 10;
    return x + y + 5;
}
```